# Flash builder 4.7 debugger failed to connect to the running application

Tags: android, flash, apache-flex

I'm trying to debug an app by connecting the device to the computer.
It keeps showing me this

"The Flash Builder debugger failed to connect to the running application. Ensure that USB debugging is enabled on the device."

It's weird because other apps seems to work fine.

- Obviously, I ensured that the USB debugging is set to enabled. Other projects works just fine.
- I tried cleaning up the project, restarting, reloading & reimporting the whole project. all doesn't work
- Running AIR simulator works. & I tried exporting release build of app and then download it in my device. This works too.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does your device show up for `adb devices`?

Answer (score 0):

I got it figured out somehow...

The facebook login part in the app.xml file was the reason. don't know why it crashes only on my device, but trying to figure it out!